# Generating static Docusaurus site for use without without webserver

Tags: docusaurus

I have recently started experimenting with Docusaurus and have managed to add pages, menu items etc.

I can run the site locally using the following

```
npm run start
```

I have also attempted to build the site using

```
npm run build
```

This seems to require that the resulting files are server through a webserver. Is it possible to build the site so they can just be accessed locally through the file system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docusaurus maintainer here.

I've just tested that yesterday and I don't think it can work easily.

I also think Docusaurus is an SPA with history.push() navigation, don't think this is compatible with the file:// protocol but not totally sure either. If my assumption is correct, not having a webserver is impossible, unless we build your site in some kind of "no js" mode, and totally disable the SPA-based navigation.

In all cases this is not a feature we support officially at the moment